# Google apps script array issues

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps-script-editor

I am working on an apps script that loads xml data into a function and parses the data based on user input.

The xml is simple and straightforward:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Records>
    <Record>
        <username>jjohnson</username>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>johnson</lastName>
        <email>john@someurl.com</email>
    </Record>
    <Record>
        <username>bsimmons</username>
        <firstName>ben</firstName>
        <lastName>simmons</lastName>
        <email>ben@someurl.com</email>
    </Record>
    ...etc
</Records>
```

The function takes the XML and loads the data into an array of objects and attempts to parse the data based on username and display the content as a row in google sheets.

```
function XMLCONTACT(username) {
var url = '<XML source>';
var ContactXml = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
var document = XmlService.parse(ContactXml);
var root = document.getRootElement();
var arr = [];
var XMLChildren = root.getChildren("Record");

for (var i = 0; i < XMLChildren.length; i++) {    
    arr.push({ 
        username: XMLChildren[i].getChild("username").getText(),
        firstName: XMLChildren[i].getChild("firstName").getText(),
        lastName: XMLChildren[i].getChild("lastName").getText(),
        email: XMLChildren[i].getChild("email").getText()
   });
}

var newarr = []

for(var j= 0; j < arr.length; j++){
  if(arr[j].username === username ){
        newarr.push(arr[j]);
  }
}
    return newarr;
}
```

The problem is that when the function runs, nothing is returned. I can get sheets to display the contents of the array without objects, but not the filtered output.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: try adding `Logger.log(arr)` somewhere and see what is logged.

Comment: Even better than `Logger`, for complex data, is to use `console` and then view (and interact!) with the logged object in Stackdriver.

Comment: How do I use the console while in google sheets? I can't see any way to open up developer tools or inspect.

Comment: @Imagesthataspire it's in the view tab

Comment: I think that your script works without errors. But I'm not sure about "The problem is that when the function runs, nothing is returned. I can get sheets to display the contents of the array without objects, but not the filtered output.". Can I ask you about the output results you want?

Comment: My intention is for the script to display only the object associated with a specific username. So when the function XMLCONTACT(jjohnson) is used, the script will return an array with only those contact details. Currently, it returns nothing.

Comment: I'm sorry. I could notice your response just now. If you reply your comments to users, please put ``@username``. By this, the user can get the notification of your reply. When ``XMLCONTACT("jjohnson")`` is run, the function returns ``[{"username":"jjohnson","firstName":"John","lastName":"johnson","email":"john@someurl.com"}]``. For this situation, can I ask you about your issue?

Comment: @Tanaike thank you for the response (and the primer on Stack. I'm still new to this). Yes, this is correct. My problem is, I cannot get this to show in sheets. How do I instruct sheets to load an array of objects in a row?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I posted my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to put the returned values from `XMLCONTACT()` to Spreadsheet. If my understand what you want, how about this modification? From your script, I thought that you may want to use `XMLCONTACT()` as a custom function for Spreadsheet. So please modify as follows.

It returns the values as 2 dimensional array.

#### From :

```
var newarr = []
for(var j= 0; j < arr.length; j++){
  if(arr[j].username === username ){
    newarr.push(arr[j]);
  }
}
return newarr;
```

#### To :

```
var newarr = [];
for(var j= 0; j < arr.length; j++){
  if(arr[j].username === username ){
    newarr.push([arr[j].username, arr[j].firstName, arr[j].lastName, arr[j].email]);
  }
}
return newarr;
```

#### Note :

- It supposes that this script is the container-bound script of Spreadsheet.
- When you use this, for example, please put `=XMLCONTACT2("jjohnson")` to a cell in spreadsheet.
- If you want to change the arrangement of values, please modify `newarr.push([arr[j].username, arr[j].firstName, arr[j].lastName, arr[j].email]);`. If you cannot understand this, please tell me.

If I misunderstand what you want to do, please tell me. I would like to modify my answer.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Imagesthataspire I'm glad your issue was solved. Thank you for all your help.